# Стрим видео с сервера\компьютера на телефон

Tags: android, android-studio

Есть идея сделать приложение, которое передает поток видео с компьютера в приложение. Идея следующая(пример). Запустить игру, включить стрим через OBS. Передавать, к примеру, на какой-то сервер. А с этого сервера как-то получить поток видео в свое приложение. У меня не столько вопрос, сколько совет. Что искать\гуглить, т.к. не знаю, что искать толком.

Answer (score 1):

Тебе нужно гуглить "rtsp client android" на https://github.com есть исходники, которые можно поизучать. Также есть советы в английской ветке, например https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42765881/best-way-to-build-a-rtsp-client-on-android